# How to use postmessage with wkwebview plugin in cordova phonegap build

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview, postmessage

I am using cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine in a phonegap app to open a web page:

```
    ref = window.open(url, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
```

All is working fine thus far, page displays properly, iOS log says the app is using wkWebView, and the display is much faster than when using UIWebView.

I want to send a postmessage from the page in the WkWebView and handle the message in my index.js running on the device.  From the WkWebView issues pages, I copied the following code into the webpage:

```
    <button type="button" name="button" onclick="sayHello()">Say hello</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("message",function(event){
            console.log("IFRAME");
            console.log(event);
        }, false);
        function sayHello(){
            parent.postMessage("Hello!","*")
        }
    </script>
```

I compile/install the app and run.  I tap the button and the debugger says that parent.postMessage executes. So now I'm ready to code the message handler on the device side.

The copied code obviously assumes that it is running inside an iframe on what I assume is the main index.html launched by Phonegap.

Before I try the iframe approach, I want to know: Has anyone has found a way to use postmessage to communicate between index.js and the WkWebView WITHOUT resorting to iframes?

For example, my window.open creates object 'ref'.  Can I simply add an event listener on 'ref' to capture the message?  If so, then I suspect I'll need to use something other than 'parent' when calling 'parent.postmessage'. What would that be?

Suggestions are good, examples are better.

Note that this app has not yet required delving into native code... Phonegap Build has been doing just fine to create my installables. I'd like to keep it that way if possible.

Comment: Are you using the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser core plugin?

Comment: Hi Shazron, thanks for asking. I do have the iframe version of messaging working, so although I am still interested in this topic, it now has a lower priority for me.  I DO have inappbrowser listed in config.xml as a plugin. I was trying to use it only for Android:                 if (device.platform === "iOS") {
                    ref = window.open(url, '_self', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
                } else {
                    ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
                }